# Colocar símbolo do euro numa tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Na minha consulta tenho duas coluna onde faço a soma de horas e a soma do valor a pagar pelo cliente nessas horas:

**Linha que soma as horas:** `CAST(SUM(SEC_TO_TIME(E.teste1))/100 AS DECIMAL (15,2)) AS QTD 1º e 2º Hora`

**Linha que soma o valor a pagar:** `SUM(CONCAT(E.Valor, '€')) AS Valor 1º e 2º Hora`

Em mysql está a mostrar os resultados desta forma como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao mostrar os dados da consulta em php pretendo mostrar a coluna das horas em formato de hora e a coluna que soma o valor a pagar com o símbolo do euro

Comment: Não dá, retorna os valores na coluna como tipo de dados `BLOB`

Comment: Funcionou, em relação ao euro resolvido e em relação à hora consegue ajudar?

Comment: Não entendi a parte da hora. Por exemplo: `2.00` seria oq?

Comment: Em vez de `2.00` devia aparecer `2:00`, porque da forma que está, dá a entender um número decimal. Mas isso é só um pormenor, senão mantenho

Comment: Funcionou, assim fica com uma apresentação profissional. Obrigado

Comment: Disponha amigo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em relação ao `CONCAT`, você está somando a a concatenação, quando deveria concatenar a soma, e converter o resultado em `CHAR`.

Use a função `CONVERT`, alterando o código para:

```
CONVERT(CONCAT(SUM(E.Valor), '€'), CHAR(8)) AS `Valor 1º e 2º Hora`
/* o 8 é o tamanho do resultado. altere conforme sua conveniência*/
```

Em relação ao formato de hora da primeira query, pode fazer um `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE(CAST(SUM(SEC_TO_TIME(E.Valor))/100 AS DECIMAL (15,2)), '.', ':')
AS QTD 1º e 2º Hora
```